# test if a ssh session is connected failed

Tags: powershell

I use `ssh-session` module 1.4 version in a PowerShell script located in a Windows Server 2008 R2 but after installing `sshsession` module 2.1.3 in a Windows Server 2019, something doesn't work!

I tried `if -not`

I tried `-eq` with a variable

```
if (! (Get-SshSession -ComputerName $MAST_NAME).connected) {
    New-SshSession -ComputerName $MAST_NAME -Username $USR_REMOTE_MAST_NAME -Password $USR_REMOTE_MAST_PASSWD
}
```

With 1.4 `ssh-session` module, the test `if (! (get .......)` worked fine.
with 2.1.3 `sshsession` module (noticed the name has changed), the code below doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an New-SshSession, an $SshSessions variable is created. Try using it to first find the required host and then check its status. For example:

```
ForEach ($SshSession in $SshSessions){
If (($SshSession.Host -eq $MAST_NAME) -and ($SshSession.Connected -eq "true")){
  Write-Host '$MAST_NAME is connected'
}
Else {
  New-SshSession -ComputerName $MAST_NAME -Creditials...}}
```